# Mailchimp API v2.0 - get subscriber name using email address

Tags: php, mailchimp

I am using mailchimp api v2 to add users to a mailchimp list with php.  I now need to retrieve existing subscriber first name and last name using their email address.  I've searched high and low for examples of this but can't find anything that easily explains how to achieve this.

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: I think what you need is this method: https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/lists/member-info.php and you can call it like this: https://benmarshall.me/mailchimp-php-api-class/#member-info. Your question is actually off-topic since you're asking for examples without showing the code that you've tried, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) at number 4. Please try some code on your own first. If you have a problem, then include the code in the question with some explanation of the problem and we'll try to help.

Comment: Thanks will give that a crack.  I actually haven't tried any code yet because I couldn't work out where to begin and couldn't find any example to get me going.  So not sure that constitutes as off-topic.  But will bear that in mind for the future.